# Read file line by line and put in other string

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I want to read file line by line and put its content to other string in specific place. I have created the below script but unable to put file content in that string.

File: cat /testing/spamword

```
spy
bots
virus
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/testing/spamword

cat $file | while read $line;

do

echo 'or ("$h_subject:" contains "'$line'")'

done
```

Output:

```
or ("$h_subject:" contains "")

or ("$h_subject:" contains "")

or ("$h_subject:" contains "")
```

The output should be like:

```
or ("$h_subject:" contains "spy")
or ("$h_subject:" contains "bots")
or ("$h_subject:" contains "virus")
```

Comment: You're using the wrong tools... Try `sed 's/.*/or ("$h_subject:" contains "&")/' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using `while read $var`. That's wrong syntax since `$var` means "the value of the variable var". What you want is `while read var` instead. Then, variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single ones, and you're trying to deal with that but in a needlessly complex way. You're also hard-coding the file name which is usually not a good idea. Finally, as a matter of style, try to avoid [UUoC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html). Putting all this together, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"    
## The -r ensures the line is read literally, without 
## treating backslashes as an escape character for the field
## and line delimiters. Setting IFS to the empty string makes
## sure leading and trailing space and tabs (found in the
## default value of $IFS) are not removed.
while IFS= read -r line
do
    ## By putting the whole thing in double quotes, we 
    ## ensure that variables are expanded and by escaping 
    ## the $ in the 1st var, we avoid its expansion. 
    echo "or ('\$h_subject:' contains '$line')"
done < "$file"
```

Note that it's [generally better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222) to use `printf` instead of `echo`. And, in this case, it even makes things simpler since you can replace the `echo` above with:

```
printf 'or ("$h_subject:" contains "%s")\n' "$line"
```

Save this as `foo.sh`. make it executable and run it with the file as an argument:

```
./foo.sh /testing/spamword
```

Answer (score 3):

use like this

```
echo "or (\$h_subject: contains $line)"
```

you should not use $line in while.. better you can use the below code.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/testing/spamword
while read line;
do
echo "or (\"\$h_subject:\" contains \"$line\")"
done < ${file}
```

Comment: but needs bots, spy and virus in commas "bots" "spy" "virus". As i have mentioned above.

Comment: Check my recent answer

Comment: according to your recent answer output is `or ($h_subject: contains bots)` but it should be `or ("$h_subject:" contains "bots")`

Comment: Answer modified... Please check now

Comment: Yup its working now, thanks for your help :)